# In keypress event AJAX request is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, keypress

I have a `<textarea>` and there I can type data. In `keypress` I have to call an ajax request.
In `keypress` I check if the key is <kbd>enter</kbd> (key code = `13`), then the ajax request should call.

**My code is**

```
$(document).keypress(function(e)
  { 
     var msg = $("#text").val();
     var user = $("#huname").val();
     if(e.which == 13)
    {
      $.post("chatAjax.php",{user:user,msg: msg}, function(data)
      {
         alert(data);
      });
        }
  });
```

**And my AJAX page is**

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];
echo $user"<br>"$msg;
```

As I told if I press <kbd>enter</kbd> the ajax page should call, but now when I press <kbd>enter</kbd> still I am in the new line of `<textarea>`.

Comment: you should add `keypress` event on `#text textarea`.

Comment: thanks for your comments and answer, but still not working.If i remove  ajax request and simply alert in the keypres event of enter key, it works. So i think the problem is with my ajax call...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it. There are two problems in my code.

1. use this

   $("textarea").keypress(function(event)

Instead of

```
$(document).keypress(function(event)
```

2. in AJAX page I miss the `concatenation (.) operator`

   echo $user."
   ".$msg;   /*right*/

But I use this and it's wrong

```
echo $user"<br>"$msg;   /*wrong*/
```

Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).keypress(function (event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        callAjaxFunction();
        event.preventDefault()
    }
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this right before the ajax call:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

As the name indicates, it will prevent the default action of the keypress event.